# PostgreSql EF, navigation property is always null when querying

Tags: entity-framework, postgresql

I stumbled upon unexpected behaviour when using Entity Framework with PostgreSql.

When I query context with navigation property inside where clause, its always null and fails. But If I add there Include method pointing to navigational propery it's working

this will work

```
context.Garages.Include("PostalCode").Where(f=>f.PostalCode.RegionId == regionId)
```

this will not (PostalCode is null and fails on NullReference)

```
context.Garages.Where(f=>f.PostalCode.RegionId == regionId)
```

I don't think I had to add this to query when using MSSQL. Can anybdoy explain this to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want that your navigation properties be [lazy loaded](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232#lazy), then you need to declare them as `virtual`:

```
public Garage
{
 //...
 public virtual PostalCode PostalCode {get;set;} 
}
```

In this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd468057(v=vs.100).aspx) you will find the conditions that must follow your entities if you want to enable lazy loading for your entities and to have the Entity Framework track changes in your classes as the changes occur.

If that navigation property is already `virtual`, the other option that I think could cause that behavior is if you turn off Lazy Loading on your context:

```
public class YourContext : DbContext 
{ 
   public YourContext() 
   { 
     this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false; 
   } 
}
```

If you call the `Include` method, you are going to load the related entity as part of the query. This load behavior is called [Eager Loading](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232#eager). On the other hand, if you use Lazy Loading, the related entity is going to be loaded the first time that  is accessed, that is the behavior that you looking for.